# Regex to match a String with asterisk

Tags: java, arrays, regex, file, regex-negation

I'm coding in Java and I want to split my string. I want to split it at.

```
/* sort */
```

Yes I plan to split a .java file that I have read as a string so I need it to include "/* sort */". I'm creating a code that sorts Arrays that are predefined in java class file.

Exactly that and do another split at

```
}
```

and then I wanted help how to go about splitting up the array since I'll be left with

an example would be this

```
final static String[] ANIMALS = new String[] /* sort */ { "eland", "antelope", "hippopotamus"};
```

My goal would be to sort that Array inside a .java file and replace it. This is my current code

```
    private void editFile() throws IOException {
    //Loads the whole Text or java file into a String
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileChoice()))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    }
    arrayCutOff = everything.split("////* sort *////");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayCutOff.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arrayCutOff[i]);
    }
}
```

This basically reads the whole .txt or .java file completely with the exact same formatting into one string. I planned to split it at /* sort */ and sort the array inside but I realized if I did that I probably can't replace it.

Comment: What are you trying to say, You sound confused. Can you please explain a little bit more using example.

Comment: @ZubairNabi just gave an example

Comment: Are you truly asking how to escape special characters in a regex? You couldn't find *any* answers to that on the web?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to repace this `{ "eland", "antelope", "hippopotamus"}' <- this array

Comment: How on earth did you come up with `"////* sort *////"` as being the Java literal for the regex matching the string `/* sort */`, given that regex escapes uses ``\``, not `/`, to escape special characters?

Comment: @ZubairNabi Yes, I wanted to sort that array and replace it back into a .java or .txt file without affecting the other code around it. I planned to do this by using a /*sort*/ right before the array starts to make it easier.

Comment: Well Well, then you should start learning updating a file in java, sorting is not a big deal, point here is you need to update a specific part of your file and replace it with the sorted array. that can be done by getting the character count to start writing from there.

Comment: You need to use `split("/\\* sort \\*/")`. The asterisks need to be escaped by a backslash, and in the string in Java the backslash itself needs to be escaped by another backslash.

Answer (score 2):

Considered your're using java 8 you might go this direction:

```
private void editFile() throws IOException {
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileChoice()));
  String content = lines.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
  Stream.of(content.split(Pattern.quote("/* sort */"))).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

However, the trick you're asking for is `Pattern.quote`, which dates back Java 5. It'll qoute a literal so it can be used as a literal in regExs and is a bit more convenient (and reliable I think) than wrestling around with backslashes...